# Make a website become a real cube

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, cube

I have recently found CSS/JS animations, like Meny: http://github.com/hakimel/meny
Thing is, it only makes one side become off-screen. My goal is, to make a whole cube'd website.

The idea: I am using technology to create native applications using web technology. To make things look really awesome, I want to implement 3D animations. Thing is, I dont want to over-stuff my main view - so I thought about having actually five - or six, depends how possible that is - faces.
Imagine that all four options of Meny are activated - Top, bottom, left, right. So when a user moves their courser to the top or any other side, they'll see one of the individual faces.
The bottom one will hold a little console window. The left will hold a search. The right will hold some informations and triggers, and the top the actual menu. The center, the always-visible face, will hold the dynamically loaded content. So this way I can use the side faces to trigger AJAX calls for the main face.

How can I realize such an animated cube-like design? The sixth face, on the backside of the front face, might be a more detailed version of the console, with actual input and such...a terminal, of sorts.

The desktop technology I use is appJS. It doesnt support 3D yet, so Illt ry different technologys. Ill debug the interface itself in Safari.

Comment: A cube in the browser with each face showing different versions of your page? Take a look at three.js - http://threejs.org/. It's a webgl library. Here's an example where someone has implemented html on a plane inside a scene - http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/CSS3D.html.

Comment: Looks very interesting, but also complicated o.o; However, Ill keep an eye on it. If nothing else will help, ill use this...somehow.

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't be too hard to do with CSS 3D tranforms. Have a look at these:

http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/cube.html

And a demo:

http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/cube-02-show-sides.html

Comment: Super interesting! Going to try out to apply this to the body and use Meny's method to auto-rotate the cube when the mouse pointer pokes a specific area. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, i went by the example, and then used the final demo to make a copy of it. Now my cube does indeed rotate...but it litterally goes up.
[code](https://gist.github.com/IngwiePhoenix/30afe0160fe0eb61d1bf)